# SwipeRefreshLayout configuration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I am working on a network project and dynamically update info. I have a few questions about the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

1. After the `onRefresh()` starts the icon won't stop spinning and will not disappear even when all the data is updated.
2. When I launch my app there is a white screen (while information is loading). If I try to make the refresh it will work but will load 2 copies of my data. Is there a way to force the `onRefresh()` method OR to disable it until my data is loaded?
3. How do I block all actions before the data is loaded?

Here is my code so that everyone understand what I am talking about:

**Main Thread:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_page);

    final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener((SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener) new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            na.eraseList();
            new NewsParser().execute();

        }
    });


    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(R.color.red);

    recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);


     na = new NewsAdapter();
     recList.setAdapter(na);
    new NewsParser().execute();



    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

**AsyncTask**:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gamedev.net/page/index.html").get();
                Element e = doc.getElementById("featured");
                Elements es = e.getElementsByClass("article_content_inner");



                for (Element el : es) {

                    Element forHeader = el.getElementsByTag("strong").first().getElementsByTag("a").first();

                    String URLforImg = el.getElementsByTag("img").first().attr("src");
                    String forDesc = el.getElementsByClass("article_desc").first().html();
                    forDesc = new String(forDesc.substring(forDesc.indexOf("</a>") + 7,forDesc.length()));
                    na.changeList(new NewCard(forHeader.html(), forDesc, URLforImg, forHeader.attr("href")));
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          na.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                      }
                                  }
                    );

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the onRefresh() starts the icon won't stop spinning and will not disappear even when all the data is updated.

Use `SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)`

> When I launch my app there is a white screen (while information is loading). If I try to make the refresh it will work but will load 2 copies of my data. Is there a way to force the onRefresh() method OR to disable it until my data is loaded?
>
> How do I block all actions before the data is loaded?

`SwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: thank you, this is almost what I want because I still get an error if I try to swipe down while it's updating. I think I might need to block UI until it `postExecute()` Any clue on that?

Comment: What do you mean? Of course you must not modify your UI outside of `postExecute()`

Comment: if I try to swipe up while the app is updating I will have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 5(offset:5).state:6` so I have to make my UI wait until the update is finished. Or fix it somehow else. How could I do it?

Comment: You don't have to make the UI wait, just avoid the user to refresh until the operation is completed use `SwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: no, it is not the case. I am not trying to update again. I am trying to scroll the content. And if I do that I get the exception

Comment: in that case the problem is another one, may be it is better if you ask a new question.

Comment: I have made a fix but it doesn't seem to me that it's a good fix. I do notifyDataSetChanged() in both preExecute and postExecute so it updates before the refresh and after the refresh. But I don't want my UI to disappear. But I think I will figure that out later.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use a new thread within asynctask. Get rid of that first. Secondly, you should update your UI in your onPostExecute method, that is where you need to call `na.notifyDataSetChanged();`Also you need to call `swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);`when you update/finish with the asynctask for disabling the loading/refreshing animation.

Regarding the white screen - why don't you put a loading spinner before you populate the list? Or populate the list using old data (that you have saved or preset in SharedPreferences ect.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice about not using a new Thread in AsyncTask. I am doing that to add each item separately. If I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `postExecute()` method it will take much longer with the blank UI. In future I am going to load a lot of information with pictures so I need to add them one by one. That is the solution I found. If there's anything better for that I would like to know. And I still get an error if I try to scroll while it is updating. So I need to block all the UI actions while it is updating. Thank you